# Recent DNS change reverts to old nameservers after change to .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, dns, nameservers

I recently migrated a site to a new hosting service. There were some problems with the SSL certificate that needed to be ironed out in the new location, so I turned off HTTPS until those issues were resolved. They are resolved now, and so I updated the .htaccess file to direct all requests to use HTTPS. But after making that change, I get the IP address of the old hosting service when I ping the URL.

Checking the URL at whatismydns.net show that the new nameservers have propagated, so I have no idea why I've reverted to the old IP address. Will it change back? Do I have to re-update my nameservers?

The domain in question is oaklandoctopus.org.

Comment: Can you share the domain name?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the domain name.

Comment: `host www.oaklandoctopus.org
www.oaklandoctopus.org is an alias for oaklandoctopus.org.
oaklandoctopus.org has address 209.182.202.36` is that the new or old IP address?

Comment: That is the new one. For me, it keeps flipping back and forth between this one and the old one: 143.95.37.82

Comment: Your global DNS settings seem fine, it always resolves to 209.182.202.36. Perhaps you just have some issue on your client side (misconfigured local DNS server, hosts file, or something)